# Модульное приложение Vue

Tags: vue.js, npm, модули, vue-router

Вопрос скорее всего глупый. С Vue познакомился неделю назад.
Решил попробовать построить модульный проект, бэк поделен на модули так, что при удалении папки модуля ничего не сломается. Теперь необходимо реализовать модульность на фронте.
Идея такова - что каждый отдельный модуль можно подключить указав JS файл, например, в HTML. Причем если его удалить - ничего не сломается. 
Пробовал реализовать гиблую идею:
Есть общий инстанс Vue, который строит основную страницу и меню на основе полученной с бэка информации о имеющихся модулях, при выборе пункта меню создается еще один инстанс внутри текущего - который уже является "модулем". Такая идея работает но она не верна в принципе, да и кроме того возникают проблемы - независимый от основного VueRouter и переход поссылке, т.к., даже если и заставить работать еще один экземпляр роутера - не будет работать прямой переход по ссылке, т.к. ссылка будет состоять из набора от двух независимых роутов.
Возник вопрос - как правильно можно построить архитектуру, да, есть компоненты, но они подключаются непосредственно до сборки проекта, что не подходит из-за идеи того, что приложение должно иметь возможность подключать новые модули без повторной сборки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я не до конца понял проблему, которую Вы решаете, но я интерпретировал ее так: Вы ищете способ передавать с сервера на фронт код какого-либо компонента, которого нет в первоначальной сборке, для дальнейшенго использования. Если моя интерпретация верна, то решение этой задачи я вижу так:
Для начала необходимо создать компоннет, который будет обрабатывать всю эту логику. Так же здесь не обойтись без встроенного во Vue компоннета под названием `component` https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component . А дальше, все просто: получаем с сервера код компонента, регистрируем его и открываем.

```js
const ServerComponent = {
  name: 'ServerComponent',
  template: `<div>Hello from server</div>`,
};

Vue.component('BaseComponent', {
  name: 'BaseComponent',
  template: `<div>Hello from base component</div>`,
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      nameComponent: 'BaseComponent',
    };
  },
  template: `<div><component :is="nameComponent"><component></div>`,
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Vue.component(ServerComponent.name, ServerComponent);
      this.nameComponent = ServerComponent.name;
    }, 2000);
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Да, Вы все поняли верно!
Как я понял, компонент
`
const ServerComponent = {
  name: 'ServerComponent',
  template: `<div>Hello from server</div>`,
};
`
Может содержаться в отдельном файле, который может быть подключен через <script>. Для сборки dev проекта я использую команду npm run dev и она формирует *.js файл. Как можно отдельно собрать компонент *.vue в *.js, чтобы уже его подключить в браузере а не передавать прямо оригинальный код компонента?
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да, этот компонент может содержаться в отдельном файле. Что же касается  перевода отдельного однофайлового компонента `.vue` в `.js` - такого никогда не делал. Это надо со сборщиком "колдовать". Задайте этот вопрос отдельно

Answer (score 0):

/src/main.js

```
document.component = function(name, component) {
    app.component(name, component)
}
document.mount = function() {
    app.mount('#app')
}
```

index.html

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.component('hello-world', HelloWorld)
     document.mount()
}
```

Разметку страницы с компонентами у вас отдает модуль?

Comment: уточняющим вопросам не место в ответе.