# Сборка Vue компонента

Tags: vue.js, npm, компоненты, модули

Ранее задавал вопрос про подключение модулей из отдельных файлов на клиенте.
Мне помогли с этой задачей, вопрос и ответ тут
[Модульное приложение Vue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1016004/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-vue)

Но, исходя из этого ответа, я на клиента должен подключать именно файлы *.vue в их исходном, чистом, виде.
Можно ли каким-то образом выполнить "компиляцию" в минимизированный *.js, наподобие той, которая выполняется при запуске команды **npm run dev**?

Comment: Вы не совсем верно поняли ответ. Компоненты могут иметь расширение как `.js` так и `.vue`.  Разница лишь в удобстве работы. Компоненты с расширением `.js` можно непосредственно подключать к странице, а с расширением `.vue` предварительно необходимо обработать, с помощью Webpack'a, например. Но, собственно, это не отменяет Ваш вопрос: "как отдельный компонент `.vue` скомпилировать в `.js`?".

Answer (score 0):

Для Vue JS 2 можно вот так попробовать:

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name HelloWorld src/components/HelloWorld.vue
```

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component

Для 3 версии вопрос актуален, там команда с параметром --target wc не работает, как собрать отдельный компонент в 3 версии?

Comment: в ответе должен быть ответ, а не новый вопрос.